# Can I have a 24" / 60cm C string on a Harp?

Tags: tuning, harp

We just got a new lever harp.  It starts at F, around 24" long.

After I tune it, I'd like to be able to play each note in increasing order, to validate the tuning.  But F Major requires B flat, which is a note I can not generate unless I tune all the B strings to B flat (so that the lever will take it to B).

As we're going to replace the strings it came with with better ones, if I'm going to change things, now is the time.  So:

1. Should I just tune all B strings to B flat?
2. Can I just start at C instead
3. Am I just completely confused?

Comment: I'm not a harpist, so just commenting: Why not just play a C major scale starting at F?  (Or call it a F Lydian mode?)  Also, isn't that "B" really a C♭?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My daughter recently started learning harp. The teacher told us to tune it by engaging (putting "up") the levers for all E, A, and B pitches, and then tuning the result to C major. Or another way of thinking of this is, with all the levers disengaged (down), the harp is in E flat major.

I guess the reasoning behind this is to let you play in the keys that have only a few sharps or flats without retuning anything: You can play in up to three flats simply by disengaging the levers that you had engaged (for E, A, and B), and you can play in up to four sharps by engaging the others (F, C, G, D). You would have to re-tune some strings to play in keys like A flat major or B major, but without retuning you can play in 8 of the most common keys. (Plus more, really; she's playing a piece in C harmonic minor right now, so she still doesn't actually need the B flat that's in the key signature.) This video explains it well:

By the way, I strongly recommend using a tuner to keep your tuning accurate; you need more than "playing the notes in order" to "validate" it. Be aware that:

- The strings will stretch, so you will need to correct the tuning frequently at first, but less so as they adjust to the correct tension, and
- As you tune, the adjustments you make can affect the pitches of other strings, even ones you've already tuned. Especially at first, I follow a strategy like:

  - Tune the middle C and all Cs above it, then all Cs below it
  - repeat with Es
  - repeat with Gs
  - So I've just tuned "in an arpeggio," leaving gaps. Now I check the strings I tuned at first, like the Cs, and correct if needed; otherwise I move on to "fill in the gaps" with D, F, A, and so on.

Oh by the way, if you plan to replace all the strings, I strongly recommend that you don't do it all at once. I mean, for one thing, literally don't take all the strings off and then start putting them on; it might be bad for the instrument to remove all the tension at once (it certainly would be for a violin). Plus, it might be hard to remember what goes where. But also, as I said, new strings stretch, and it could be nice to give them all a chance to do some of the worst stretching one at a time. I might replace them in a pattern similar to how I described tuning, starting in the middle range. If the harp is playable right now, I might take my time, replacing one or two strings per day. (Or, then again, I might get impatient for the day when they've all settled in, and get it over with a bit faster.)

Also, be aware that when you buy a harp "string," you often get a length of gut that will allow you to get at least two "strings" (two sounding lengths) out of it by cutting it in half. This is good, since they inevitably break, and you want to have those backups! Finally, note how the knots are tied in the ends of the existing strings. The lower notes probably have the knot tied around a short length of spare string, used as a sort of crosspiece to help keep the knot in place.

Comment: "By the way, I strongly recommend using a tuner to keep your tuning accurate; you need more than "playing the notes in order" to "validate" it."-> I use a tuner.  But when it's all done, and the tuner's been happy, I want to hear that it's sounding right

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, middle C on my harp is very close to 60cm.

If it's a fully levered harp, then the most common tuning is Eb major with all the levers down (off).  So the A's, E's and B's are all tuned flat, and the others are tuned natural.  Then if you put the B, E and A levers up, you get C major.  That tuning can do all major keys from Eb Major to E major, as well as the relative minors of those.

If it's not fully levered, then you'll have to work out what works best.  It's common to have levers on the strings that are often sharped - e.g. F, C and G.  Or on the strings that are often flattened, e.g. B, E and A.

If you're going to re-string it, do one string at a time.  Harps don't like having all the tension removed.  Some will even fall apart.  It is possible to change the tuning, or to use different types of string (gut, nylon or fluorocarbon).  But that needs a lot of care.  If the new strings have a higher tension that the old ones, the harp may self-destruct.  Lower tension is always possible, but the sound may be disappointing.